# API specification file with actual data

Tags: openapi, swagger-2.0

I have my API Security product. I want the customer to upload an API specification file from which I can perform further things. But for that, I want an API specification file with actual data like if it has /*balance* endpoint then I want the actual API Key as well as the value of all the required parameters.

The main question is how the customer can add the actual API key and values for the required parameters in the Swagger JSON file.

The **value** property doesn't parse while parsing the Swagger JSON file.

I tried example and value property but it doesn't parse it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenAPI/Swagger file formats describe the general shape of an API, they don't include data and so I don't think they're the right solution for your situation. This isn't the answer you want, but you should choose a format that supports your use case, could be as simple as a JSON file to represent the data.